# How i can get the true sum of base DLL address and its offsets on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I don't know much about С++ and ctypes, please don't kick me right away).

If this question was already asked - sorry.

I'm writing a program to track the state of the character in the game.

I have a fragment python code, with it help I want to get someone value from memory, but I don't comprehend how I can sum base DLL address and its offsets..

```
# with pywin32 get pid and loaded modules

.....

for i in range(len(modules)):
dllName = re.search('NWindow.DLL', win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(processHandle,modules[i]))

if dllName:
    dllAddress = modules[i]
    print(hex(dllAddress),win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(processHandle,modules[i]))
    break
processHandle.close()

dllAddress += 0x009CF49C      # Base DLL address + something from CE ..:D
offsets = [0x5AC, 0x200, 0x268, 0x6C4, 0x240]  # Offsets list

buffer = (ctypes.c_byte * 4)()
bytesRead = ctypes.c_ulonglong(0)
pHandle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, False, get_pid('process.exe'))

ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, dllAddress+sum(offsets), buffer, len(buffer), 
ctypes.byref(bytesRead))

print(struct.unpack('i', buffer)[0])
```

For example: 
[from Cheat Engine i get this view (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnh1d.png)

Adding up the address of the desired DLL and its offsets in python I do not get the same address as CE:

CE: 0x0F386E40
Py: 0xDAD07B4
And of course, i cant get true value from wrong address.. But if i just put (dynamic)address which found by CE, i get true value.

I dont have enough knowledge of working with RAM, help me please..)
I hope I made the question clear..

UPD: yeah, i did it)

```
def get_address(base_address, offsets):
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, base_address, buffer, 
                                             len(buffer), ctypes.byref(bytesRead))
    addr = struct.unpack('i', buffer)[0]

    for i in range(len(offsets)-1):

        addr += offsets[i]
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, addr, buffer, 
                                                 len(buffer), ctypes.byref(bytesRead))
        addr = struct.unpack('i', buffer)[0]

    result = addr + offsets[len(offsets)-1]
    return result
```